# Converting a string into the Date datatype and inserting into the database

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2010

I have a rent_date and return_date column in rental table and the data-type is Date. I have created two different strings for them. rentDate is the current date and returnDate is the output of adding the days that the product is rented for, from the current date. I tried to convert the strings using to_date but its showing errors. I have tried it with the data-type varchar2(30). Worked fine. But had to modify to Date because I want a late return date too. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query?

```
DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Now;
string rentDate = dt.ToString();

// this is added to the current date of the user input and showed in the form
string returnDate = label66.Text;

string Query = "Insert into rental ( pr_ID, cid, rent_date, Return_date, status, receipt_no) values ( '" + comboBox5.Text + "' , '" + comboBox4.Text + "', (to_date('" + rentDate + "','dd/mm/yyyy')), (to_date('" + returnDate + "','dd/mm/yyyy')), '" + Status + "', '" + txt_recpt.Text + "') ";
```

Comment: Why do you keep your `DateTime` values as a `string`? [This is completely wrong](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). Why don't you pass your `DateTime` values directly to you insert query? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: I totally agree with "Soner" in the earlier comment. Don't do that string concat - go with parameterized queries instead!!!

http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: Cause I could not pass the DateTime value in the dd/mm/yyyy format direct in the query. How can I do it? I'm stuck here for days.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting?

I agree with the "Soner" that they should not be text values. However, based on your existing code, you may be getting a format error.

What format is the string value of "rentDate" and "returnDate" in? It needs to be the same as what you've specified in the INSERT query, which is "dd/mm/yyyy". If it's not, an error will be thrown.

The second parameter of the [TO_DATE](http://www.completeitprofessional.com/oracle-to_date/) function is the format of the input variable.

Unless you're getting a different error?